# Batch file help copy text between two matching strings only

Tags: string, batch-file

So i have a log text file that looks like this....but with thousands more entries and need to copy the data from 801 C down to the next Nr to a new text (really only need the data from the lines with timestamps) so i can change the 3 under Std-Id to 27 since that is the only data available for every timestamp line that ties that line to that color Standard and their a multiple ones that share the same number due to how the standards are stored in the spectrometer. Also the entry for 801 C may show up multiple times in the same log and being able to capture all instances were both stings appear to extract the text between would be needed.

```
      Nr:END                              Std-Id          L*          a*          b*
             VS410  SN:000178                                                   
             D65/10?         
       Std   801 C:START                           3       30.21       -0.02       -0.54     
         1   12/2/2019 2:17:45 AM          3       30.03       -0.03       -0.60
         2   12/2/2019 2:18:39 AM          3       29.89       -0.01       -0.71          
      Nr:END                              Std-Id          L*          a*          b*
             VS410  SN:000178   
             D65/10?                                                        
       Std   706 C                         6       35.17        2.79        1.17  
         1   12/2/2019 8:47:54 AM          6       35.22        2.50        0.62     
         2   12/2/2019 8:48:06 AM          6       35.45        2.50        0.63    
      Nr:END                              Std-Id          L*          a*          b*
             VS410  SN:000178   
             D65/10?   
       Std   706 BBA                       5       34.55        3.06        1.16
         1   12/2/2019 10:35:05 AM         5       36.55        2.68        0.66
         2   12/2/2019 10:35:35 AM         5       35.38        2.73        0.66
      Nr:END                              Std-Id          L*          a*          b*
             VS410  SN:000178   
             D65/10?   
       Std   703 C                         3       34.55        3.06        1.16
         1   12/2/2019 10:35:05 AM         3       36.55        2.68        0.66
         2   12/2/2019 10:35:35 AM         3       35.38        2.73        0.66
```

Expected output below

```
       Std   801 C:START                           3       30.21       -0.02       -0.54     
         1   12/2/2019 2:17:45 AM          3       30.03       -0.03       -0.60
         2   12/2/2019 2:18:39 AM          3       29.89       -0.01       -0.71          
      Nr:END                              Std-Id          L*          a*
```

What i currently get

```
      Nr:END                              Std-Id          L*          a*          b*
             VS410  SN:000178                                                   
             D65/10?         
       Std   801 C:START                           3       30.21       -0.02       -0.54     
         1   12/2/2019 2:17:45 AM          3       30.03       -0.03       -0.60
         2   12/2/2019 2:18:39 AM          3       29.89       -0.01       -0.71          
      Nr:END                              Std-Id          L*          a*          b*
             VS410  SN:000178   
             D65/10?                                                        
       Std   706 C                         6       35.17        2.79        1.17  
         1   12/2/2019 8:47:54 AM          6       35.22        2.50        0.62     
         2   12/2/2019 8:48:06 AM          6       35.45        2.50        0.63    
      Nr:END                              Std-Id          L*          a*          b*
             VS410  SN:000178   
             D65/10?   
       Std   706 BBA                       5       34.55        3.06        1.16
         1   12/2/2019 10:35:05 AM         5       36.55        2.68        0.66
         2   12/2/2019 10:35:35 AM         5       35.38        2.73        0.66
      Nr:END                              Std-Id          L*          a*          b*
\u001a
```

Ive tried using this batch file by changing 801 C to 801 C:START and Nr to the Nr:END. But it captures more than the first :END

```
@echo off
setlocal enableExtensions enableDelayedExpansion

set "source=G:\800SeriesFilter.txt"
set "target=G:\800Series.txt"


set "include=lines.tmp.txt"
set "source_n=source_n.tmp.txt"

> "%include%" (
    set "line="
    for /f "tokens=1 delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /n "START END" "%source%"') do (
        if defined line (
            for /l %%c in (!line!, 1, %%~a) do (
                echo(%%~c:
            )
            set "line="
        ) else (
            set "line=%%~a"
        )       
    )
)
> "%source_n%" findstr /n "^" "%source%"

setlocal enableExtensions disableDelayedExpansion
> "%target%" (
    for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /B /L /G:"%include%" "%source_n%"') do @echo(%%b
)

del "%include%"
del "%source_n%"

endlocal
endlocal
goto :eof
```

Trying to go with Batch or Vb-Script or anything that requires no input from the user to run. Trying to automate the process of dynamically building an excel document so anyone can double click a shortcut it ftp's the logs and adds the needed tables and graphs. I have been smacking my head into this issue for a few days and have not found a sure way to get it done and doesn't help that i am very novice with batch file commands and vb-script.

Comment: Add to your question the following: What OS? What version OS? 32 or 64-bit?

Comment: @somebadhat The batch-file tag already states that the question is about windows batch files, and the information about 32 or 64 bit is irrelavant to the question. Even the version of the OS is irrelevant, as batch file syntax hasn't changed since Win-XP

Comment: I don't understand `But it captures more than the first :END`, there is no `END` in you original file. Perhaps you should also show, what output you expect

Comment: Edited my question to reflect how i have been trying to extract the text.

Comment: So with the current way I am trying to get this to work it finds the first :START and every :END after to the very last :END and copies all the data between. I want it to find the first :START and first :END copy those lines to a new file and then continue on its merry way through the rest of the document finding data between only a :START and :END.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could search for the first `START` and store only that line number.
Then read the file again ut skip all line before the stat line number.

Then echo each line until the first `END` is detected.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "source=800SeriesFilter.txt"
set "target=800Series.txt"

set "lineno_start="
for /f "tokens=1 delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /n "START" "%source%"') do (
    set /a lineno_start=%%a-1
    goto :break
)
:break
set lineno_start

for /f "skip=%lineno_start% tokens=1,* delims=:" %%a in (%source%) do (
    set "line=%%b"
    echo(#!line!
    echo(!line! | findstr "END" > nul && goto :break
)
:break
```